# Schubert calculus and the representation ring of the general linear algebra

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, enumerative-geometry, schubert-calculus

Schubert calculus studies the structural constants of the standard basis of the cohomology ring of the quantum Grassmannians. It is well known that it is isomorphic to the fusion ring of the category of finite-dimensional representations of the Lie algebra $\frak{gl}_n$. But you first discivered this isomorphism? Is it somehow obvious if you know the Littlewood--Richardson rules for $\frak{gl}_n$ irreps?

Comment: Don't know for sure "who first discovered" this, but D. Peterson did a lot of unpublished work in the 90s on the quantum cohomology of Grassmannians and other flag varieties, and many foundational results are (at least partly) attributed to him.

Comment: @Sam: Thanks for the comment, but I would guess this result was well-known even in the 90s . . .

Comment: But of course I could be wrong!

Comment: Here's a '93 paper by Witten attributing the observation to Gepner. '91. https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9312104

Comment: @AllenKnutson: Thanks a lot!